# How to present the 'greater than or equal' in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using ReportLab to create PDF documents. I'm importing text from .txt files to Python so these texts display in my document.
For things to look nice, I would like to display the literal 'greater than or equal' symbol in my document.

How can I present the symbol `≥` in the .txt file (not `>=`) in a way Python understands?
Same question for 'less than or equal' symbol.

Thank you!

Comment: Just use it?.. Paste `≥` into your text file, it can be loaded as usual UTF8 content. If you need to eval the expression, just `content = content.replace('≥', '>=')` and voila - it's understandable for python. You can also do reverse transformation to replace all `>=` with `≥` literals.

Comment: Note that there also exist fonts specifically tuned for coding that have ligatures for these cases, e.g. [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode). This strictly alters the rendering only, not the characters, but that may be exactly what you need anyway.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.